# W2K8 server running IIS7 VS Express Web Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, iis-7

(EDIT) - I decided to make this page more like instructions since i have figured this out.

Deploy my VS Express 2013 Web Application to an MS Server on my LAN running:

**Windows Server 2008 Standard
IIS 7.0
MS SQL Express**

This is some information to help anyone with a similar situation.

I can access the Web Application locally (from VS Express) when I click Debug - Start Debugging.  ALSO - At this point it is connected to the MS SQL Express Server on my LAN and not a local database.

Time to publish the Web Application to my IIS 7 Server!!!

NOTE - The method below WORKS FOR ME.  There might be better ways to do it but I found any info on  this exact setup very limited.

VS Express 2013 Web Deploy pre-reqs:
(on IIS 7 Server)
-Web Deploy is installed, http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy
-Set Up Security on Web Deploy, this site helps:
http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy

In Project:

1. Right Click your project name, choose PUBLISH...
2. PROFILE - Name or import your profile
3. CONNECTION
   -Server: LAN address of your IIS server
   -Site Name:  Name of Site on IIS
   -User/Pass:  (Credentials you set up earlier in Prerequisites)
   -Destination URL: (I leave blank for now)
4. SETTINGS - Click the arrow below FILE PUBLISH OPTIONS and check the 'Exclude App Data' setting (this is assuming you are running MS SQL on the IIS Server).

   - Select your Database string, it should be in the drop down list)
5. PREVIEW - Web Deploy will give you errors when you try to PREVIEW, resolve these errors using MS Websties, Stack Overflow, etc. **WHEN YOU GET THIS ERROR:  "#ERROR_FRAMEWORK_VERSIONS_DO_NOT_MATCH" (full Error message below), your Web Deployment is ready
6. PUBLISH the web deployment, it wont work, thats okay.  It creates a publish profile
7. Right-click the project and choose PUBLISH again, this time use under the CONNECTION tab choose WEB DEPLOYMENT PACKAGE, take note of your folder location (Step 8).  All the database/file settings should be the same (doublecheck if you like), PUBLISH the Web Deployment package
8. Log onto your IIS Administration (on the Server), right click the NAME of the Server (top level) and choose DEPLOY - IMPORT SITE.  Navigate to the folder where you saved the package in step 7. (or transfer it with a USB Stick, etc)

IMPORTANT - When importing the profile, at the second screen, UNCHECK the boxes related to .NET 32-Bit etc.  (there are two of them)

1. Leave everything else on defaults and import the site (successfully?).
2. At this point when I browse the site from IIS I get a 403 Forbidden Error.
   I fixed this using code from comment below:

After that my Web App was from the IIS Server.  I'm continuing with MVC tutorials found here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5

I'm hoping once I understand enough about MVC and EF6 I can connect the Web App to MySQL rather than MS SQL and still build Code First Applications.  If anyone has info on that please post it in the comments.

If this post helped you please Vote up top, I'm new to the STACK.

**Full Error Message from post above:
Web deployment task failed. (The versions of the .NET Framework Configuration Provider (rootWebConfig32) are different on the source (4.0) and destination (2.0).  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FRAMEWORK_VERSIONS_DO_NOT_MATCH.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue might be permissions.  What is your authentication set to?  In debug mode, you're typically working as yourself, whereas if you deploy, you are setup as a different user, most likely anonymous.  With that in mind, you should be able to correct your problem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of things.  I finally got it working.

I created a Deployment package following instructions found on MS site and others.

Before Publishing my deployment package, I ran a "Preview" (PREVIEW section of the wizard).  This was bringing up various errors related to Security and other issues I fixed using MS support sites.

WHAT I FOUND ON MY OWN - (Its fairly simple), after you create the Deployment package without issue, go to IIS on the Server side, click the Server Name in IIS (top level) and choose Deploy - Import Package.  In the second or thu=ird step there is a screen where you select items to be imoported (mine had everything checked).  I UNCHECKED the two related to .NET Config files and imported it.  Voila, it worked.

It still wasn't letting me view the site.  I had to add this line to the web.config file and it fixed everything.

```
 <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
 </system.webServer>
```

If anyone wants a mored etailed description of what I did let me know and I will try and redo my process/tutorial with more exact instructions.

Comment: Ah ha!  That would be the other setting that remains ever elusive.  Good catch and glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

to get the same publish behaviors with direct publish from VS, you can uncheck following box : properties\Package/PublishWeb\include IIS express settings as configured in ISS express